# Fetch data from 4 tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables as below

Table1: `restos`
Structure:

```
resu_id    resu_name     resu_address
-------------------------------------
   1      ABC             Exapmple
   2      DEF             Example
   3      GHD             Example
```

Table2:`foodtype`
Structure:

```
id    typename
---------------
 12    Indian
 23    Punjabi
```

Table3: `resto_foodtypes`
Structure:

```
resu_id    foodty_id
--------------------
  1          12
  2          23
  3          12
```

Table4: `discnts`
Structure:

```
id    resu_id    amt_dscPer(%age discount)
---------------------------
 19     1          15
 20     2          25
```

Now i want to display the restaurant along with discounts available for the restauarant.
Currently restaurants are getting displayed but for the restaurant not present in `discnts` table are returning null values from `discnts` table.

below is the query that m using

```
SELECT * from `restos` r  join resto_foodtypes rf on rf.resu_id = r.resu_id 
join foodtype f on rf.foodty_id = f.id left join discnts dcfm on 
r.resu_id= dcfm.resu_id where true;
```

I want that the restaurants that are not present in `discnts` table should not be included in resultset. For e.g. `resu_id=3` is not present in `discnts` table.

Comment: @Jens. i mistyped here.. now corrected

Comment: `where true` ? What do you want ?

Comment: try left join instead of join

Comment: As I can see, you should get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude results that have no entry in discnts table, use a `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

To include these results, but have a `0` displayed (instead of the defaults `NULL`), you can use `IFNULL(expr, 0)` function:

```
SELECT 
  r.resu_name AS Name, 
  f.typename AS Food,
  IFNULL(dcfm.amt_dscPer, 0) AS Discount
FROM `restos` r 
JOIN resto_foodtypes rf ON rf.resu_id = r.resu_id 
JOIN foodtype f ON rf.foodty_id = f.id 
LEFT JOIN discnts dcfm ON r.resu_id= dcfm.resu_id;
```

IFNULL returns the first parameter if it is not null, the second if `expr` is indeed null.

Comment: i do not want the results to be excluded. All restaurants should be displayed but discounts shall be displayed as 0

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question, see updated answer for new solution.